# java - Show, how much time passed by executing a class?

Tags: java, class, sorting, time, calculation

Im C++ coder but somehow today I ended with Java, so I did little project with some sorting algorithms (I made them into classes) and I wonder, is it possible to println passed time of calculation of a class ? Not whole project but only one class ? So I can compare theese algorithms.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You can use `System.currentTimeMillis()` to get the current time in milliseconds since epoch.

Comment: @devgianlu Better to use [`System.nanoTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime--), for more precision, when calculating *elapsed* time.

Comment: And for the record: you are supposed to do serious research prior posting questions. An experience coder could know how to first use a search engine ... to find answer in way less time than required to put a question here.

Comment: One executes a merthod, not a class., That being said, the simple solution is System.nanoTime(). For the correct solution, look up Java Microbenchmark. One of teh first things that pop up is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current time at the beginning and at the end of the code, and subtract them:

```
long s = System.nanoTime();

//Your code;

long elapsed = System.nanoTime() - s;
```

Your time elapsed will be in nanoseconds, but it's an easy conversion.